# Is /usr/local/opt/php54/bin/php alright compared to /usr/local/bin/php?

Tags: php, macos, terminal

I'm just a starter with these things, so I want to know if having my php in the first directory fine. It got installed there using homebrew, but I think it should be installed in the second directory.

```
/usr/local/opt/php54/bin/php
```

shows up when I type type in "which php."

I use Mac OS X 10.8. Whenever I type in "php" in the Terminal, it goes to PHP but it just ends there. Just a blank thing.

Comment: location don't matter. > `Whenever I type in "php" in the Terminal, it goes to PHP but it just ends there. Just a blank thing.` (I think this is the standard behavior)

Comment: Location doesn't matter, as long as PHP is on the $PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executing `php` from the commandline without any arguments it's waiting for input from STDIN.

The installation location does not really matter (depending on what are you doing of course). If you can execute PHP by just entering `php` everything's fine.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know that it's normal.